Multiple line in caption of marginfigure, in tufte-book documentclass
I am using the tufte-book documentclass. I just want to be able to write multiple paragraphs in the caption of marignfigure. If I write this
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph.

This should be another paragraph.
}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}

then the output is

which is clearly flawed.

Use \\\  instead o a blank line

I don't get the error shown.  I get "Figure 1" in the first line.  Are your packages up to date?

@JohnKormylo I compiled that in overleaf, and specifically, the screenshot is from the pdf output from overleaf. I am not aware of the state of the packages of overleaf. I also get this error on my local Latex set up, but I would have to check if all my packages are up to date.

@Mane32 That does work, thank you.

Multiple paragraphs are not possible, but you can insert line breaks and obtain your desired output:
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a paragraph This is a paragraph This is a paragraph.\\
This should be another paragraph.
}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}

